# How to use asyncstorage in ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I made localstorage in ReactJS that works well.
But I want to use this code to React-native.
I am confused how I can apply to
This code is of ReactJs.

```
...
  componentWillMount(){
    const contactData = localStorage.contactData;
    if(contactData){
      this.setState({
        contactData:JSON.parse(contactData)
      })
    }
  }
...
...
  componentWillMount(){
    const contactData = localStorage.contactData;
    if(contactData){
      this.setState({
        contactData:JSON.parse(contactData)
      })
    }
  }
...
```

I read this "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html"
But I don't understand well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the React-native storage, you have to use the AsyncStorage. Above Code in react-native will become.

```
...
async componentWillMount(){
const contactData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('contactData');
if(contactData){
  this.setState({
    contactData:JSON.parse(contactData)
  })
}
}
...
...
async componentWillMount(){
const contactData = localStorage.getItem('contactData');
if(contactData){
  this.setState({
    contactData:JSON.parse(contactData)
  })
}
}
...
```

You can either use the async-await or then/catch promise for handling the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
    this.retrieveItem(goalCategory).then((goals) => {
              //this callback is executed when your Promise is resolved
              }).catch((error) => {
              //this callback is executed when your Promise is rejected
              console.log('Promise is rejected with error: ' + error);
              }); 

//the functionality of the retrieveItem is shown below
async retrieveItem(key) {
    try {
      const retrievedItem =  await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      const item = JSON.parse(retrievedItem);
      return item;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
    return
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Save to AsyncStorage

```
const saveUserId = async userId => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', userId);
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

> Retrieve a value from AsyncStorage

```
    const getUserId = async () => {
          try {
            const uid = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId');
             console.log(uid);
              } catch (error) {
                // Error retrieving data
                console.log(error.message);
              }
            };
```

> Delete from AsyncStorage

```
const deleteUserId = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('userId');
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```